# Regex - string optionally ends with asterisk

Tags: regex, url

I need to create a regex to validate urls. Currently the regex I am using allows one or multiple occurrences of /text.

For example:

```
/text/text

/text

Regex: ^(\/[a-zA-Z\d\-\_]+)+?$
```

My requirement is I want to use this regex in a validator such that it allows /* in urls but only at the end.
For example:

```
/text/text/*    - Valid

/text/*         - Valid

/text/*/text    - invalid
```

Can someone please help me out with this? Thanks

Comment: Read a regex tutorial or you will have 100s of questions like this.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @hwnd: first <°))))))))))))))))>

Comment: Yes, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\/([\w-]*)(\/\1)*((?!\1)[\w-\/])*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP4pZ2/16

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: Thanks, but /text/text/*text works which is not desirable for me. If /* exists it should exist only at the end of the url plus the url should contain a-zA-z, any digit, hyphen and an underscore only.

Comment: @vks thanks, so close! but again [a-zA-Z\d\-\_] is important as it should only contain letters, digits, hyphen and underscore only

Comment: @vks it still accepts &, %, $, etc. Just a-z, A-Z, 0-9 digits, underscore and hyphen should be allowed

Comment: @vks it doesn't accept /* at the end :( Sorry I did not add that it should accept /* at the end as well. If you have an updated solution that will be nice, I will look at regex tutorials because I am a noob with this. Thank you

Comment: @vks The regex should validate that the string can contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscore, hyphen and an asterisk (*) but if * exists in the string it should be only at the end and only once.
Consider the following example:
/text/test-01/text_01/**   - VALID
/text/test-01/*text_01/*  - INVALID
/text/test-01/*/text_01   - INVALID